# Buttons are not visible when the page has more no.of.rows (data) while running selenium webdriver script

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am running my tests in Firefox browser and the scenario is below. I have a page with many rows of data and a Create/delete/View All buttons. By default i see 50 rows of data displayed at a time. If i want to see more, i click the Next/Prev buttons to go page by page or i can use View All button to see all the data in single page.
I need to select a particular row and hit delete button to delete the record.
The problem is selenium code works fine when i click View All to display all the records in single page, select the one i want to delete But the buttons are not visible and the test fails. I have around 700+ data.
I tried using wait and sleep methods but still when the code runs, the buttons are not visible at the top of the page.
Is it because of the larger no.of data? How to work around this and have the buttons visible?
Note - If i select the record at the top of page (within first 100's for example), buttons are visible. But when i select a record at the middle or bottom of the page, buttons are not visible.

The buttons are in form id=designList.(deleteBtn)And the data are under the table id="designListTable".

```
<form id="designList" class="items-stack" method="post" action="cms" name="designList">
<div class="container">
<div id="designControlsContainer" class="float-left">
<span id="" class=" ">
<input id="newBtn" class="font-bold btn " type="submit" title="" alt="" name="newBtn" value="New" accesskey="n">
</span>
<span id="" class="">
<input id="removeBtn" class="font-bold btn" type="submit" title="" alt="" name="removeBtn" value="Remove" accesskey="r">
</span>
<span id="" class="">
<input id="moveBtn" class="font-bold btn" type="submit" title="" alt="" name="moveBtn" value="Move" accesskey="m">
</span>
<span id="" class="">
<input id="deleteBtn" class="font-bold btn" type="submit" title="" alt="" name="deleteBtn" value="Delete" accesskey="d">
</span>
</div>
<div class="float-right">
</div>
<table id="designListTable" class="listing-table">
<colgroup>
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<td class="no-wrap locked-container">
<a id="itemLink.224819" href="cms?action=templateDetail&itemID=224819&getLock=Y&folderID=0" title="001047 final verification on preview from IE 8 (ID#: 224819 Version#: 21)"> 001047 final verification </a>
   <input id="lockedBy.224819" type="hidden" value="" name="lockedBy.224819">
</td>
<td class="no-wrap"> </td>
<td title=""> </td>
<td class="no-wrap"> savefolder </td>
<td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td class="no-wrap"> 09/30/15 - 01:15PM </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<td class="no-wrap locked-container">
<td class="no-wrap"> </td>
<td title=""> </td>
<td class="no-wrap"> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td class="no-wrap"> 01/20/15 - 01:44PM </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: please share the HTML of the buttons you are trying to click, and the code that you've tried so that we can help you

Comment: See if the page is getting scrolled and buttons are on the top of the page. It wouldn't be displayed. You need to perform a scroll up operation once you have selected the desired data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scroll down by JavascriptExecutor

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,110)", "");
```

Then check button is click-able by follwoing code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//xpath")));
```

And then click on button.

Comment: Thanks. I used the JavascriptExector Click method to directly click on the button eventhough it was not visible on the screen and it worked.

Comment: If it worked for you then please accept this as an answer so that other people can refer it. Thanks